Запятая в сочетании " такой(,) как": Погода дождливая, такая(,) как осенью
Как правильно расставить знаки:
Погода дождливая(,) такая(,) как осенью.

Я знаю как, ведь ответ есть в Справочнике по пунктуации: Погода дождливая, такая как осенью.

Но пользователи непременно хотят поставить вторую запятую тоже и активно протестуют: они привыкли ставить запятую перед КАК. Правило такое есть, что же им, переучивать все правила?
Вариант (с запятой перед КАК) правильнее, не находите? Но комп не 
исправляет и первый вариант (без запятой), и вот уже у всех студиозусов 
в курсовых и дипломных махрово цветет вариант "такие как". А почему 
комп не исправляет? Может, его покурдячить пора? Или это такая новая 
норма, наряду с кофием среднего рода?


Так кто же прав и кого "курдячить" надо? Можно ли это доказать с помощью грамматики, чтобы не было таких споров? А также чтобы не сожалеть о трудных правилах русского письма? Как мне кажется, все эти правила логичные и предельно обоснованные. Только не учить их надо, а понимать.



ну исходя из прошлой логики, если "как осенью" - это "не осенью", то запятая нужна, т.к. сравнение; а если "как осенью" - это "потому что осень на дворе", то запятая не нужна, то есть "погода дождливая, такая осенняя".

Я думаю, что разные ситуации нельзя обозначить знаками препинания. Решение в обоих случаях одно.

Рассмотрим вариант: Погода дождливая, такая, как осенью.
Похоже на перечислительную интонацию. Если я в процессе речи делаю паузу после "такая", то на письме это выглядело бы так:
Погода дождливая, такая... как осенью. Или так:
Погода дождливая... такая, как осенью. Или сплошным многоточием.
Уберём одно слово:
Погода дождливая, как осенью.
Короткое сообщение. Одна пауза. Сохраняем двухчастную структуру, добавив убранное слово:
Погода дождливая, такая как осенью.
Всё на месте. "Такая", если я не ошибаюсь, тяготеет к указательным местоимениям, может быть и наверняка является здесь подлежащим. "Как осенью" его сказуемое.
В быстром разговоре, по-моему, слово "такая" вообще лишнее.
А кудрячить надо только протестующего... да и споров там нет.

Спасибо! Все ваши замечания удивительным образом соответствует истине (как я ее понимаю, начитавшись книжек): про интонацию и двухчастную структуру, про указательное местоимение и сказуемое, а также про лишнее слово "такая".  Ну просто все совпало! Интуиция, да?)

@Sharon  Не столько интуиция, сколько знание правила и опыт с вами :)

Нет, это именно чувство и восприятие языка, что я ценю выше книжных знаний.  Может, и с Хармсом заодно разберетесь?)  Я это предложение нашла вчера вечером, и попыталась вспомнить какие-нибудь правила. Потом решила, что утром вспомню, но увы)  Надо что-нибудь по интонации подобрать...

@Sharon Посмотрел, и на своё удивление согласен с отвечающим.  На замечание «Вы написали с ошибкой» ответствуй: «Так всегда выглядит в моём написании». Если ставим первое двоеточие, то тогда так: На замечание: «Вы написали с ошибкой» – ответствуй: «Так всегда выглядит в моём написании».  (Как бэ по праивлам.)

Присоединительное тире похоже по движению тона, но пауза там маловата. Может, единый знак для замены ТОЧКИ лучше  подойдет, он более универсален по тону, а пауза больше?   А многоточие? //  И правило какое, есть ли аналоги в языке с таким оформлением? Или этот абсурд по Хармсу совершенно уникален?

@Sharon Единый знак не пойдёт, он будет полностью разрывать "На замечание ответствуй". А тире я вижу по аналогии с примерами, где прямая речь вклинивается туда, где не нужны знаки: Он сказал: "Труль-ля-ля" – и вышел покурить.

Понятно, спасибо. А точка у Хармса разве не разрывала предложение? Тогда я за многоточие, оно хотя бы немного абсурдное)) Ладно, подожду, может, кто чего придумает.  Здесь - единый знак  https://telegra.ph/EHto-avtorskaya-punktuaciya-ili-oshibki-russkih-pisatelej-04-14

Комментарий к ответу
Совершенно с вам согласна, и вот почему.

Запятая перед КАК ставится в предложении: Погода такая дождлИвая, // как Осенью. При перестановке получаем те же две (не три!) фразы: Погода дождлИвая, // такая / как Осенью.  Это парный вариант. Еще один вариант: Погода такая, // как осенью.

О грамматике


Оборот с союзом КАК соотносится с соответствующим придаточным предложением, в данном случае это выглядит так:
Погода такая дождливая, какая бывает осенью. Такая — указательное слово в определительном придаточном.
Погода  такая,  какая бывает осенью. Такая — указательное слово (на правах сказуемого!) в местоименно-определительном придаточном.

Другие варианты с оборотом

Погода  дождливая, как осенью. Погода дождливая, как будто осенью. Союз КАК БУДТО.

Вывод

Как ни запишешь, получаются две фразы, именно такое здесь произношение. И в грамматике выделяется сложное союзное соединение ТАКОЙ КАК без расчленения. Аналогично есть соединение ТАКОЙ ЖЕ КАК.
Можно сравнить с нерасчлененным союзом ТАК ЖЕ КАК у Розенталя: Наша группа досрочно сдала все зачёты, так же как параллельная — без расчленения сложного союза; Невозможно задержать развитие общества, так же как невозможно повернуть назад колесо истории;
P. S. Информация достаточно известная, например:  Редакторское бюро «По правилам»

Действительно, рука так и тянется поставить запятую. Возможно, по аналогии: погода такая дождливая, как осенью. Люди машинально ставят запятую. Даже я, если бы не знал правил, поставил запятую.

@Серж  Народ в Сети об этом же говорит, а еще обсуждают, насколько "новое" это правило. Как бы не было его раньше! Я же думаю, что ему просто не уделяли должного внимания.  Нашла старый учебник Валгиной (1994 год), там говорится в примечаниях только о союзном соединении ТАК ЖЕ(,) КАК.  (И вообще по теме сравнительных оборотов  мало материала.)  А соединение  ТАК ЖЕ(,) КАК есть и в Справочнике  https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/spravochnik-po-punktuatsii/tak-zhe-kak-i
